# Python/Tornado - call to classmethod

Tags: python, python-2.7, tornado, class-method, motorengine

Given this simple code where I declare a class and a functions inside it. In the main I try to call the function but the call is not made. I don't get any error but if I put a print in order to know if the call has happened nothing occurs.

### models

```
class Balance(Document):
    gross_balance = FloatField(required=True, min_value=0, default=0)

    @classmethod
    def createBalance(cls, gross_balance):
        result = yield Balance.objects.create(gross_balance = gross_balance)
        result.save()
    @classmethod
    def sayHi(cls):
        print "Hi there"
```

### main

```
from models import Balance

class CreateBalanceHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

@tornado.gen.coroutine
def post(self):
    gross_balance = self.get_argument('gross_balance')
    Balance.createBalance(gross_balance)
    Balance.sayHi()
    self.redirect('/query/{}'.format(gross_balance))
```

What am I doing wrong? The sayHi function show its print but there's no reaction with createBalance.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Post a [mcve].

Comment: @VincentSavard I've posted a more complete example

Comment: Is that your actual indentation, with `createBalance` outside the class body?

Comment: Also, I'm not familiar with tornado, but that `Balance.createBalance(gross_balance)` call is only creating a coroutine, not executing any of its code. Are you supposed to `yield from` that coroutine or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Decorate `createBalance` with `gen.coroutine` to run it on ioloop. To wait until balance is created invoke it like `yield Balance.createBalance()` in `RequestHandler`

models

```
class Balance(Document):
    gross_balance = FloatField(required=True, min_value=0, default=0)

    # classmethod must be the most outter decorator (as well as staticmethod)

    @classmethod
    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def createBalance(cls, gross_balance):
        result = yield Balance.objects.create(gross_balance = gross_balance)
        # AFAIR save returns future and also should be yielded
        # yield. result.save()
        result.save()

    @classmethod
    def sayHi(cls):
        print "Hi there"
```

main

```
from models import Balance

class CreateBalanceHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):

    @tornado.gen.coroutine
    def post(self):
        gross_balance = self.get_argument('gross_balance')
        yield Balance.createBalance(gross_balance)
        Balance.sayHi()
        self.redirect('/query/{}'.format(gross_balance))
```

Note: As I mentioned in snippet's comment, in motorengine the `Document.save` returns `Future` and probably you want to `yield` it as well, to wait until it has finished.